# Unable to: add-apt-repository in Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, lxd

I'm trying to install LXD in Ubuntu Server 14.04 following [this post](https://www.zenly.co.uk/installing-lxd-on-ubuntu-trusty-tahr-5-minute-guide/).

I have done that successfully in the past in other similar setups, but this time is throwing this error:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-lxc/lxd-stable
sh: 1: /usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSources/mintSources.py: not found
```

Searching for any solution, most of the pages suggest a broken/mixed Mint installation, however I have never -ever- installed Mint in that server (It has been 14.04 all the way since it was acquired).
It has no extra repositories besides the official ones.

The server is updated with the last versions, so I'm puzzled about this one.

Any idea why is that happening?

Comment: I decided to install the repository manually. Still I wondering why that happened.

Comment: Here's the thing. Your error msg says it _can't_ find mintSoursces.py. The Ubuntu version of add-apt-repository does not look for that script, but...the Mint version does. (See [Mint version of add-apt-repository](https://github.com/linuxmint/mintsources/blob/master/usr/bin/add-apt-repository). And I think you tried something once that you might not remember, perhaps a ppa meant for Mint. Idk. Check your sources lists (don't forget to look in sources.d). If you find something, take it out, update, and reinstall add-apt-repository.

Comment: @chaskes: Yes, you were right. Can you post it as answer please? For some reason, `software-properties-common` was not installed. Not sure when or why, but I could have added some repository which I later removed (and it left the package hanging there somehow). Thanks for pointing it out. I removed that file and installed the correct package and its now working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error message says it can't find `mintSoursces.py`.

The Ubuntu version of `add-apt-repository` does not look for that script, but...the Mint version does. (See the [Mint version of add-apt-repository](https://github.com/linuxmint/mintsources/blob/master/usr/bin/add-apt-repository) ). So you somehow ended up with the Mint version of `add-apt-repository`.

It looks like you probably tried something once that you might not remember, perhaps trying a ppa or other software meant for Mint. I don't know for sure, but you may have have left something behind when you cleaned that up.

Check your sources lists (don't forget to look in sources.d). If you find something, take it out, run `apt update`, and reinstall `add-apt-repository`.